# How to insert selected value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

I need to insert values to my table 2 with id from table 1 where name equals to 'abc'. I mean smth like this:

```
INSERT INTO tab2 (id, f_id, name, date) 
VALUES (uuid(), (here selected id where name = 'abc'), name, date)
```

How can I do it? I tried smth like this:

```
BEGIN
     DECLARE f_id char(36);
END
SET @f_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = u_email)
INSERT INTO tab2 (id, f_id, name, date) 
VALUES (uuid(),@f_id,'cba',getdate())
```

but it doesn't work. This is just my attempt at the principle maybe it will work.

Comment: Use insert..select rather than insert..values

Comment: But how to use it when I need to insert new values but with existing f_id

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sample code :

```
INSERT INTO tab2 (id, f_id, name, date) 
    SELECT uuid(),id,'cba',getdate() FROM users WHERE email = u_email
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Please test SQL queries or commands before proposing them as answers. Then you'll see your answer here can't work in MySQL.

Comment: I checked before sending

Comment: So how do you use GETDATE() in MySQL? https://dbfiddle.uk/ibELIDRf

Comment: getdate can be a custom function